# How to filter files based on file status in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

When I add a new file at local, the file status is **unknown** and the file color is brown. But that file somehow isn't shown in the dialog Commit Changes until I explicit add it to the repository.

[image]

The real problem is I can barely remember how many files I created after a long working day. Could someone tell me how to get IntelliJ to **show all unknown files**?

Thanks in advance

File Status Highlights in IntelliJ Idea:
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/file-status-highlights.html

Answer (score 1):

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>
2. click on Local
3. click on 'Unversioned Files (n directories and m files) Click to browse)'
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad +</kbd> select all files that have to be added to version control click on '+'

Comment: I really appreciate for your quick answer

Comment: Thank you @HungTran. If it works for you then you can accept it as correct. This will help your future questions receive quick answers.